# How to I set the Elastic Beanstalk solution stack via a config file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to change my solution stack name to

64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)

...and I would like to do this WITHOUT using the management console or the command line, but by placing a config file in my repository.

The reason for this is that I would like everything about my environment to be defined in code, rather than by using the CLI or the online management console.

I have tried placing the following in ./ebextensions/autoscaling_group.config:

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    SolutionStack: "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)"
    InstanceType: t2.micro
    IamInstanceProfile: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
    EC2KeyName: "eb-services"
```

....but nothing happens and my solution stack name doesn't change.

Does anyone happen to know an example of a configuration file I can use to change the solution stack when I deploy?

Thanks,
Louise

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your .ebextension file is incorrectly formatted. Try the format below:

```
option_settings:
- namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
  option_name: InstanceType
  value: 't2.micro'

- namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
  option_name: SolutionStack
  value: '64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)'

- namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
  option_name: IamInstanceProfile
  value: 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role'

- namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
  option_name: EC2KeyName
  value: 'eb-services'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that's the correct format. As described here: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html) , AWS supports a shorthand format.

I will test this anyway and let you know :)

Comment: This doesn't work - (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'SolutionStackName'): Unknown configuration setting. Also tried with SolutionStack. Maybe this setting is in a different namespace?